# Prevent pdb or pytest set_trace from being committed using a pre commit hook

Tags: python, git, githooks

I'd like to create a git pre commit hook that prevents an uncommented `pytest.set_trace()` or a `pdb.set_trace()` and other `.set_trace()`. This is because I debug from the command line often and sometimes forget that I left the debug statement in the code. By using a pre commit hook, I should be able to avoid this in the future.

[Keul's Blog](http://blog.keul.it/2013/11/no-more-pdbsettrace-committed-git-pre.html) has a solution for this but the session has to be in the root directory of the git repo for it to work or it will complain.

I basically want the `not` equivalent of this to work in `grep`

```
#(\s+)?.*\.set_trace\(\)
```

See the [regexr](http://regexr.com/3ee33) test

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct regular expression is `^\s?[^#]+\.set_trace\(\)`

Explanation:

1. `^` starts with
2. `\s?` matches a space or more or no space
3. `[^#]+` matches any characters excluding `#`
4. `\.set_trace\(\)` matches any function ending with `.set_trace()`

   - we can be more explicit by only including `pdb` or `pytest` `set_trace`s but there may be other packages that also have a `set_trace`

Sample python code

```py
import pdb

if __name__ == "__main__":
      pdb.set_trace()
      pytest.set_trace()
      # pdb.set_trace()
      #       pytest.set_trace()
      #pytest.set_trace()
# pdb.set_trace()
      # somethingelse.set_trace()
```

Verify using [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```bash
$ rg '^\s?[^#]+\.set_trace\(\)'
main.py
4:      pdb.set_trace()
5:      pytest.set_trace()
```

Now we can use [`git-secrets`](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets#installing-git-secrets) which gets triggered on a pre-commit hook and this will prevent us from committing this line

```bash
$ git secrets --add '^\s?[^#]+\.set_trace\(\)'
$ git add main.py
$ git commit -m 'test'
main.py:4:      pdb.set_trace()
main.py:5:      pytest.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is also a pre-commit configuration to check for debugger imports (found it thanks to this [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-commit-hooks-you-must-know-ff247f5feb7e)):

`.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
---
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
      # Check for debugger imports and py37+ breakpoint() calls
      - id: debug-statements
```